# Kubuntu: Slow Program Start - ca 4 sec

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I.e. KCalc needs 4 sec from Command to Launch. Kate too. Libre Office Writer Splash Screen appears instantly. So I tried to install another graphics driver (INtel OO), didnt help. I did check /etc/hosts, its fine. .xession-errors contains some of these

```
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 16835, resource id:         92312108, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
```

and after I launch "kate" this:

```
kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" ) to KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" )
kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" ) to KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" )
kscreen.kded: Change detected
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 26563, resource id: 130023446, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" ) to KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" )
kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" ) to KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" )
kscreen.kded: Change detected
kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" ) to KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" )
kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" ) to KScreen::Output(Id: 68 , Name: "HDMI1" ) ( "HDMI1" )
kscreen.kded: Saving current config to file
kscreen.kded: Calculating config ID for KScreen::Config(0x2326d90)
kscreen.kded:   Part of the Id:  "bd0a13e9dbd6a6e0ce1ce255d4e55c33"
kscreen.kded:   Part of the Id:  "ea466ee9ba98ce5da7c4befbd68d6103"
kscreen.kded:   Config ID: "b38fa8b4e98d646d3928ac6c11d4d061"
kscreen.kded: Config saved on:      "/home/x/.local/share/kscreen/b38fa8b4e98d646d3928ac6c11d4d061"
```

When I launch kate in a shell, no error messages appear in the shell.

How could I debug this? Is there a possibility to watch what the system does while launching a kde-app?

Comment: Problem gone because of newly install. Didnt find the cause.